# Is "the pundits tell firms" correct? How to analyse "pundits" "tell" "firms"?

Tags: grammar

> Interbrand, a consultant on branding, describes authenticity as “an internal truth and capability”, a “defined heritage” and a “well-grounded value set”. This slippery quality, the pundits tell firms, is what the public is yearning for, in an age of doubt and mistrust.

From The Economist's [“Authenticity” is being peddled as a cure for drooping brands](http://www.economist.com/news/business/21678216-authenticity-being-peddled-cure-drooping-brands-its-real-thing)

To make sense, “firm” should be a verb, while tell should be a noun. According to the dictionary, it is a verb. If it could be a noun, usually it would go like this “the pundit tell” in which “pundit” modifies “tell”, or “the pundits’ tell”. “The pundits tell” is still odd. So I need help. Thanks!

Comment: One of the simplest possible English sentence forms is subject/verb/object.  *Pundits* is a noun and is the subject, *tell* is a verb, *firms* is a noun and is the object.

Comment: That sentence could be re-written, "The pundits tell firms that this slippery quality is what the public is yearning for in an age of doubt and mistrust."

Comment: "Firm", if you're still wondering, is another term for "company", "business", or "corporation".

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the confusion is with parts of speech represented by the words.

- *Pundits* is the plural of *pundit* and is a noun (though one that might occasionally be "verbified" in informal writing).
- *Tell* is a verb in this case -- to *tell* is to *speak to*.  There is also the noun *tell*, meaning a clue that someone may unintentionally give another in, eg, poker, but there's no way for that to be the meaning here.
- *Firm* in this case is a noun, meaning a business or corporation.  *Firm* is also an adjective meaning "stiff" or "hard", or a verb meaning to become stiff or hard, but those senses do not work here.

So the phrase means "pundits speak to corporations".

Answer (score 0):

What might be causing the confusion is the *function* of the clause:

> *the pundits tell firms*

This is an ***adjective clause*** as used in the context of its sentence. Its entire purpose is to modify the noun which precedes it: **quality**.

As a *clause* (as opposed to a *phrase*) it must contain a verb. In this case, that verb is **tell**. The subject is **pundits**. And the clause object is **firms**.

You can think of this *modifying clause* as a sentence within a sentence; the sole purpose of which is to modify the noun **quality**.